# Crew member’s visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My boyfriend is currently on a contract and is finishing in Oct. he wants to come and visit me in the uk for a short time before he goes back to SA. Will he be allowed entry into the uk with the Schengen Multi visa or the C1/D visa he has been issued with.

Comment: His nationality?

Comment: @NeanDerThal "SA" usually means South African

Comment: @burgi yes, but just to make sure, maybe he is goung back to SA but he is not from SA.

Comment: @Burgi But it's the ISO code for Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @svick And even then, he might be going back to Saudi Arabia but not a Saudi national.

Answer (score 13):

Schengen visa *does not* allow him to enter the UK, nor does the US crew visa (C1/D).

Crewmembers do not need a visa to enter the UK *only when they are a part of an operating crew*, but when entering as passengers **they will need to obtain a UK visa**.

Comment: How would he apply over one when he is still cruising? Would he have to go back to SA then apply for one?

Comment: @Michelle Your boyfriend can apply online from any country providing he can attend a biometric appointment at a visa application centre, and can supply the required documentation https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply

Comment: @Nean Der Thai That’s generally true for Schengen visas, but not for UK or USA

Comment: @Traveller I suspect you have it reversed: The UK and USA don't generally care what country you apply for a visitor visa from. Schengen countries are more restrictive and require applicants to apply from their country of residence in most circumstances (because the Schengen agreement requires this).

Comment: @Michael Hampton Yes, I know. The OP’s boyfriend wants a UK visa, Nean Der Thal’s comment states the BF can only apply from his country of residence, which is not true.

Answer (score 2):

The UK is not part of Schengen. Your boyfriend may require a visa to enter the UK, depending on his nationality. If he is South African, he needs a visa. You can check here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa